# Race condition in MySQL query? Reducing inventory

Tags: mysql, transactions, isolation

Each item (stock) in the inventory is modelled as a row.

```
stock
=====
code: primary key
itemType: foreign key to items table
available: boolean
```

So to reduce stock what is done is something like:

```
UPDATE stock SET available = false where code = 'something' and available = true
```

This is done in a transaction. So it looks like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE stock SET available = false where code = 'something1' and available = true;
UPDATE stock SET available = false where code = 'something2' and available = true;
UPDATE stock SET available = false where code = 'something3' and available = true;
COMMIT;
```

I suspect a race condition is possible. If I have 2 queries like the above running at approximately the same time, would they both succeed?

Comment: Need more context of what this 'transaction group' is.

Comment: @user2864740, added more info on what I meant by transaction

Answer (score 0):

They will not be done exactly at the same time (for one database).

Only one by one.

1 - succeed. (affected rows MAYBE > 0)

2 - not succeed. (affected rows = 0)

So everithing is ok.

BTW there is nothing in your query that can break things if even both succeedd at the same time (if it will be possible)...

Comment: RE: "*there is nothing in your query that can break things if even both succeed*". If both succeeds, problem is I would have given the same item twice. Ok but good to know this is not the problem

Comment: sorry? UPDATE can not give u any item at all i guess? only change its properties? INSERT - yea, may give u some new item

Comment: in this case, available is like a flag indicating availability of an item. If both updates are successful, its like saying its possible to give an item twice. Hope its clearer?

Comment: if "getting an item logic" depends on affected rows of update-query - yes. but this will not happen